# Obtener registro que este una sola vez en la tabla SQL

Tags: sql

Sinceramente no se como obtener de una tabla los registros que se encuentren una sola vez.

por ejemplo tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
identificacion atestado
1111           a
1111           b
2222           a
2222           b
3333           a
4444           c
```

lo que necesito es una consulta donde solo obtenga las identificaciones que estén una sola vez en la tabla y que contengan el atestado "a"

para el ejemplo la consulta solo deberia de devolver:

```
identificacion atestado
3333           a
```

intente haciendo esta consulta:

```
SELECT eh.identificacion,COUNT(*) FROM tabla
  GROUP BY eh.identificacion
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

pero no se como especificarle que solo muestre los que contengan el atestado 'a'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes agregar otra condición en el `HAVING`:

```
SELECT identificacion,COUNT(*) 
FROM tabla
GROUP BY identificacion
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
AND MIN(atestado) = 'a'
;
```

Comment: muchas gracias era lo que  necesitaba

Comment: Si era lo que necesitabas, no te olvides de aceptar la respuesta dandole al tilde @FranciscoAraya